# Error BC30002 " 'Global.xxx.xxx.My_Project.My.MySettings' is not defined." How can I fix this?

Tags: .net

So I have this project I've been working on for years, and boy howdy is it sweet. However the other day my computer up and died. I got the solution folder off the SSD, bought a new machine, and installed Visual Studio 2022. When I try to run the debugger, it fails to build, with the error :

```
Error BC30002 Type 'Global.xxx.xxx.My_Project.My.MySettings' is not defined.
```

The xxx being the project's name. The relevant file seems to be Settings.Designer.vb, the relevant line being:

```
Friend ReadOnly Property Settings() As Global.xxx.xxx.My_Project.My.MySettings      67
```

However, VS offers me the chance to run the last successful build, which runs fine. And of course there were no problems when it was on my previous machine.

So my question is, what can I do to correct this? I guess I need to define it, but where/how should I do this? And if it can't be corrected, can I revert the project to what it was for the last successful build?

Thanks for any insight that may be forthcoming.

Comment: Probably a version compatibility issue. Make sure you're compiling all your assemblies and the main solution on the proper version of .NET.